# Bind "this" pointer to a volatile object

Tags: c++, class, pointers

The following member function of the class `net` has the purpose to "solve" a network of nodes from the class `node`. During this process, which is carried out by the function `net::solve_self()`, the private members of `net` are overwritten and destroyed by the algorithms of `net::solve_self()`.

```
float net::solve(node *a, node *b) {
  net netsolve = *this;

  return netsolve.solve_self(a, b);
}
```

Instead I need to preserve all of these members as they initially are when `net::solve()` is called. So my idea was to launch the self-destructive function on a dummy copy of the real `net` object, to preserve the original and still get my return value.

However, `net::solve_self()` internally makes use of the `this` pointer, which unavoidably keeps to refer to the original `net` object rather than to the dummy `netsolve` object, hence the original one is destroyed in spite of the clone.

Can the `this` pointer be rebound to the `netsolve` object? 
Or otherwise how can this be solved?

Comment: Based on the code you show, inside `solve_self`, `this` is a pointer to `netsolve`, not the original `net` object.

Comment: That is correct. I've blown myself with JavaScript.